# Shift one row by ID in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shift

I have data frame, I want to create a new variable "Begin1" with condition: if the the second row of variable "Begin" smaller than variable "End" of first row, set value of "End" replace "Begin" due to overlap by ID

```
ID <- c(rep(1,3), rep(3, 5), rep(4,4))
Begin <- c(0,2.5,5, 7,8,7,25,25,10,15,17,20)
End <- c(1.5,3.5,6, 7.5,8,11,29,35, 12,19,21,28)
df <- data.frame(ID, Begin, End)
df
    ID Begin  End
1   1   0.0  1.5
2   1   2.5  3.5
3   1   5.0  6.0
4   3   7.0  7.5
5   3   8.0  8.0
6   3   7.0 11.0**
7   3  25.0 29.0
8   3  25.0 35.0**
9   4  10.0 12.0
10  4  15.0 19.0
11  4  17.0 21.0**
12  4  20.0 28.0**
```

If you can see, the rows bolded, row (6,8,11,12). Start with row 6 with ID 3, you see the "Begin" = 7.0, it's smaller the "End" of previous row, now we set "Begin1" = 8.0. For row 8 with ID 3, "Begin"=25, it's smaller than previous "End" = 29, now we set"Begin1" = 29 and so on. Here is the output

```
   ID Begin Begin1  End
1   1   0.0    0.0  1.5
2   1   2.5    2.5  3.5
3   1   5.0    5.0  6.0
4   3   7.0    7.0  7.5
5   3   8.0    8.0  8.0
6   3   7.0    8.0 11.0**
7   3  25.0   25.0 29.0
8   3  25.0   29.0 35.0**
9   4  10.0   10.0 12.0
10  4  15.0   15.0 19.0
11  4  17.0   19.0 21.0**
12  4  20.0   21.0 28.0**
```

Thanks for your advice

Here is update

```
ID <- c(rep(1,3), rep(3, 5), rep(4,4))
Group <-c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2)
Begin <- c(0,2.5,5, 7,8,7,25,25,10,15,17,20)
End <- c(1.5,3.5,6, 7.5,8,11,29,35, 12,19,21,28)
df <- data.frame(ID,Group, Begin, End)
```

This time I want to group by ID and Group, I got error from data.table.

This is output

```
   ID Group Begin  End Begin1
1   1   1   0.0  1.5    0.0
2   1   1   2.5  3.5    2.5
3   1   2   5.0  6.0    5.0
4   3   1   7.0  7.5    7.0
5   3   1   8.0  8.0    8.0
6   3   1   7.0 11.0    8.0
7   3   2  25.0 29.0   25.0
8   3   2  25.0 35.0   29.0
9   4   1  10.0 12.0   35.0
10  4   1  15.0 19.0   15.0
11  4   1  17.0 21.0   19.0
12  4   2  20.0 28.0   20.0**** Right here is not change bc it's group 2
```

Here is result from dplyr package, it works, but data.table is not working

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID, Group) %>% 
  mutate(Begin1 = pmax(Begin, lag(End), na.rm =TRUE))

Source: local data frame [12 x 5]
Groups: ID, Group [6]

      ID Group Begin   End Begin1
    (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)  (dbl)
1      1     1   0.0   1.5    0.0
2      1     1   2.5   3.5    2.5
3      1     2   5.0   6.0    5.0
4      3     1   7.0   7.5    7.0
5      3     1   8.0   8.0    8.0
6      3     1   7.0  11.0    8.0
7      3     2  25.0  29.0   25.0
8      3     2  25.0  35.0   29.0
9      4     1  10.0  12.0   10.0
10     4     1  15.0  19.0   15.0
11     4     1  17.0  21.0   19.0
12     4     2  20.0  28.0   20.0**** It works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Begin1 := Begin]
i1 <- df[, .I[Begin < shift(End, fill = Begin[1L])], by = ID]$V1
df$Begin1[i1] <- df$End[i1-1]
df
#     ID Begin  End Begin1
# 1:  1   0.0  1.5    0.0
# 2:  1   2.5  3.5    2.5
# 3:  1   5.0  6.0    5.0
# 4:  3   7.0  7.5    7.0
# 5:  3   8.0  8.0    8.0
# 6:  3   7.0 11.0    8.0
# 7:  3  25.0 29.0   25.0
# 8:  3  25.0 35.0   29.0
# 9:  4  10.0 12.0   10.0
#10:  4  15.0 19.0   15.0
#11:  4  17.0 21.0   19.0
#12:  4  20.0 28.0   21.0
```

Or another option is

```
setDT(df)[, Begin1 := shift(End), by = ID][!which(Begin < Begin1), Begin1:= Begin]
df
#    ID Begin  End Begin1
# 1:  1   0.0  1.5    0.0
# 2:  1   2.5  3.5    2.5
# 3:  1   5.0  6.0    5.0
# 4:  3   7.0  7.5    7.0
# 5:  3   8.0  8.0    8.0
# 6:  3   7.0 11.0    8.0
# 7:  3  25.0 29.0   25.0
# 8:  3  25.0 35.0   29.0
# 9:  4  10.0 12.0   10.0
#10:  4  15.0 19.0   15.0
#11:  4  17.0 21.0   19.0
#12:  4  20.0 28.0   21.0
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Begin1 = pmax(Begin, lag(End), na.rm =TRUE))
#      ID Begin   End Begin1
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      1   0.0   1.5    0.0
#2      1   2.5   3.5    2.5
#3      1   5.0   6.0    5.0
#4      3   7.0   7.5    7.0
#5      3   8.0   8.0    8.0
#6      3   7.0  11.0    8.0
#7      3  25.0  29.0   25.0
#8      3  25.0  35.0   29.0
#9      4  10.0  12.0   10.0
#10     4  15.0  19.0   15.0
#11     4  17.0  21.0   19.0
#12     4  20.0  28.0   21.0
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's new data

```
setDT(df)[, Begin1 := shift(End), by = .(ID, Group)][
                   !which(Begin < Begin1), Begin1 := Begin]
df
#     ID Group Begin  End Begin1
#1:  1     1   0.0  1.5    0.0
#2:  1     1   2.5  3.5    2.5
#3:  1     2   5.0  6.0    5.0
#4:  3     1   7.0  7.5    7.0
#5:  3     1   8.0  8.0    8.0
#6:  3     1   7.0 11.0    8.0
#7:  3     2  25.0 29.0   25.0
#8:  3     2  25.0 35.0   29.0
#9:  4     1  10.0 12.0   10.0
#10: 4     1  15.0 19.0   15.0
#11: 4     1  17.0 21.0   19.0
#12: 4     2  20.0 28.0   20.0
```

Comment: Can you exaplain for me why we use fill = Begin[1L], thanks

Comment: I add another ID2 in data.table, I use setDT(df)[, Begin1 := shift(End), by = .(ID, ID2)][!which(Begin < Begin1), Begin1:= Begin]
df, it gives me error, while dplyr didn't give me error, here is ID2 "ID2 <-c(1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2)"

Comment: @Stat Can you update your post so that I can understand it.

Comment: @ give me error  Error in .get_variables(formula, data, id, debug.info) : 
  'formula' must be a formula or a list

Comment: @Stat  what is the data,table version you have?

Comment: data.table's Version 1.9.6

Comment: @Stat I don't know if that is a problem, but I am using 1.9.7

Comment: install new version get this error "Error in list(ID, Group) : could not find function "summaryBy""

Comment: @Stat That is strange error.  So far, it is working fine for me.

Comment: what do you mean? All of your code work, the problem is my data.table packages, it works for only ID, I will figure out today

Answer (score 7):

A different way using `data.table`.  The keys are the following.

- The `by` statement which does the calculation by the ID
- The `shift` function, which lags the End variable to compare with Begin
- The `pmax` function, which does an element-wise `max` calculation

Here is the code:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, Begin1 := pmax(Begin, shift(End, type = 'lag'), na.rm = TRUE), by = ID]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach with base R creating the column using `ifelse` based on the `lag` of the `End` column.

```
df$Begin1 <- ifelse(df$Begin <= lag(df$End), lag(df$End), df$Begin)
df$Begin1[which(is.na(df$Begin1))] <- df$Begin[which(is.na(df$Begin1))]

> df
   ID Begin  End Begin1
1   1   0.0  1.5    0.0
2   1   2.5  3.5    2.5
3   1   5.0  6.0    5.0
4   3   7.0  7.5    7.0
5   3   8.0  8.0    8.0
6   3   7.0 11.0    8.0
7   3  25.0 29.0   25.0
8   3  25.0 35.0   29.0
9   4  10.0 12.0   35.0
10  4  15.0 19.0   15.0
11  4  17.0 21.0   19.0
12  4  20.0 28.0   21.0
```